# Intercept outgoing URL's using python

Tags: internet, python

So, I have a Windows computer and it has three web browsers. IE, Chrome and Firefox. Is it possible to have a Python script capture the URL's going out of the browser and store them in a variable?

Is there a way to make the Python script redirect to other url's? Squid didn't let me do this. Is there a way to manipulate the URL's being intercepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you are asking is to set up some kind of proxy server in front of the browsers and make have proxy server capture logs of the HTTP requests. You could read the log files with Python.

Consider proxy tools such as Burp and Fiddler.

Otherwise you would need to run some kind of process debugger or network traffic sniffer (e.g. wireshark).

Comment: How do I use wire Shark?

Comment: @jakekimds that is a completely different question and way harder than a tool that *only* operates at the HTTP layer (like a web proxy).  However... I googled for you: http://wiki.wireshark.org/Python